# Why is nuget installing a bunch of system namespace references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to install a library from nuget. I was expecting maybe 3 or 4 different dependencies, but it's installed a whole load of `System` dependencies?

Here is the log:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'TwitchLib.Client.2.1.4' with respect to project 'Twitch Logs', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'TwitchLib.Client.2.1.4' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'TwitchLib.Client.2.1.4'
Resolved actions to install package 'TwitchLib.Client.2.1.4'
Adding package 'Serilog.2.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'Serilog.2.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'Serilog.2.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Serilog 2.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Collections.4.0.11' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Collections.4.0.11' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Collections.4.0.11' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Collections 4.0.11' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Collections.Concurrent.4.0.12' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Collections.Concurrent.4.0.12' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Collections.Concurrent.4.0.12' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Collections.Concurrent 4.0.12' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Collections.Specialized.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Collections.Specialized.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Collections.Specialized.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Collections.Specialized 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.0.11' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.0.11' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.0.11' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.0.11' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Globalization.4.0.11' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Globalization.4.0.11' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Globalization.4.0.11' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Globalization 4.0.11' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Linq.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Linq.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Linq.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Linq 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Net.NameResolution.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Net.NameResolution.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Net.NameResolution.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Net.NameResolution 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Net.Sockets.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Net.Sockets.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Net.Sockets.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Reflection.4.1.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Reflection.4.1.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Reflection.4.1.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Reflection 4.1.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Resources.ResourceManager.4.0.1' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Resources.ResourceManager.4.0.1' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Resources.ResourceManager.4.0.1' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.0.1' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Runtime.Extensions.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Runtime.Extensions.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Runtime.Extensions.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Runtime.Extensions 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.1.0.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.1.0.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'Serilog.Extensions.Logging.2.0.2' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'Serilog.Extensions.Logging.2.0.2' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'Serilog.Extensions.Logging.2.0.2' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Serilog.Extensions.Logging 2.0.2' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Net.Security.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Net.Security.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Net.Security.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Net.Security 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'SuperSocket.ClientEngine.Core.0.10.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'SuperSocket.ClientEngine.Core.0.10.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'SuperSocket.ClientEngine.Core.0.10.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'SuperSocket.ClientEngine.Core 0.10.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Text.RegularExpressions 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Threading.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Threading.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Threading.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Threading 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'System.Threading.Timer.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Threading.Timer.4.3.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'System.Threading.Timer.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'System.Threading.Timer 4.3.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'TwitchLib.Client.Enums.1.0.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'TwitchLib.Client.Enums.1.0.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'TwitchLib.Client.Enums.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'TwitchLib.Client.Enums 1.0.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'TwitchLib.Client.Models.1.0.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'TwitchLib.Client.Models.1.0.0' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'TwitchLib.Client.Models.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'TwitchLib.Client.Models 1.0.0' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'WebSocket4Net.0.15.2' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'WebSocket4Net.0.15.2' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'WebSocket4Net.0.15.2' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'WebSocket4Net 0.15.2' to Twitch Logs
Adding package 'TwitchLib.Client.2.1.4' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'TwitchLib.Client.2.1.4' to folder '\\jgdc01\Users\RyanPearce\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Twitch Logs\packages'
Added package 'TwitchLib.Client.2.1.4' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'TwitchLib.Client 2.1.4' to Twitch Logs
========== Finished ==========
```

This ends up making my `packages` folder over 100mb full of unwanted libs.

Never experienced this before.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's fairly normal, just the dependencies of all the libs...

Comment: It's because the library targets .NET Standard. In .NET Standard, your application has every library it needs rather than depending on the Windows-provided versions (as the application may not run on Windows)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I am afraid it is an issue about the dependency package `WebSocket4Net`. Because this project target to `.NETFramework,Version=v4.6'. It seems this package pull the dependencies of .NETStandard 1.3 to the .net framework project. I have seen this issue before https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/953. If I am mistaken, please let me know for free. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is nuget installing a bunch of system namespace references?

I am afraid it may be an issue about the dependency of package `TwitchLib.Client`, `WebSocket4Net` and `SuperSocket.ClientEngine.Core`.

After checking the error log, you can find following info:

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
>   'TwitchLib.Client.2.1.4' with respect to project 'Twitch Logs',
>   targeting '**.NETFramework,Version=v4.6**'

It means the target framework is **`.NET 4.6`** rather than `.NET Standard`.

To reproduce this issue,  I created a project target `.net 4.6`, then installed the nuget package `WebSocket4Net`, **However**, the confirmation window shows up it lists dependencies under installing section, which seem to be pulled from `WebSocket4Net` `.NETStandard 1.3` list of dependencies:

[image]

I have already reported a similar issue before [NuGet install the wrong dependencies](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/953), you can try to install `Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.8.2` to the C# project with .net 4.5.2. This issue was fixed at version 5.8.3.

So, to resolve this issue, we need to contact to the author of this package to update this package. Same issue for the package `SuperSocket.ClientEngine.Core`.

Note: If you do not want add those System dependencies to your project you can delete them from your project.

Hope this helps.